# Redundant vertices when scaling polygon with boost geometry buffer

Tags: c++, boost, buffer, polygon, boost-geometry

I'm using boost geometry to manage some polygons, and I need to both expand and shrink them by given amounts. I'm using boost::geometry::buffer to accomplish this, and I'm wondering if there's a better alternative. My concern is that if I expand, say, a rectangle I end up with a polygon with 12 vertices (8 of them being irrelevant). Here's some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

using point_t = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using polygon_t = boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_t>;
using mpolygon_t = boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<polygon_t>;

mpolygon_t expand_polygon(const polygon_t& polygon,
                          const double distance) {
    mpolygon_t scaled_polygon;
    // DistanceStrategy is symmetric; want straight lines (no curves)
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::distance_symmetric<double>
      distance_strategy{distance};

    // SideStrategy is straight; grow equally on all sides
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::side_straight side_strategy;

    // JoinStrategy is miter; 1.0 as limit; Sharp (not rounded) joins
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::join_miter join_strategy;

    // EndStrategy is flat; flat (not rounded) ends
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::end_flat end_strategy;

    // PointStrategy is square; squares, not circles, if poly is just a point
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::point_square point_strategy;

    boost::geometry::buffer(polygon, scaled_polygon,
                            distance_strategy,
                            side_strategy,
                            join_strategy,
                            end_strategy,
                            point_strategy);

    // return scaled polygon offset by supplied distance
    return scaled_polygon;
}

int main() {
    using boost::geometry::get;
    polygon_t rect;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((5 5,5 8,8 8,8 5, 5 5))", rect);
    mpolygon_t expanded_mpoly = expand_polygon(rect, 1.0);
    auto list_coordinates = [](const point_t& pt) {
                                std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
                                std::cout << "vertex(" << get<0>(pt)
                                          << ", " << get<1>(pt) << ")" << std::endl;
                            };
    boost::geometry::for_each_point(expanded_mpoly, list_coordinates);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
vertex(4, 5)
vertex(4, 8)
vertex(4, 9)
vertex(5, 9)
vertex(8, 9)
vertex(9, 9)
vertex(9, 8)
vertex(9, 5)
vertex(9, 4)
vertex(8, 4)
vertex(5, 4)
vertex(4, 4)
vertex(4, 5)
```

Is there a strategy argument that I need to provide? Some other fiefdom of boost I should be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost contains `simplify` algorithm (it uses [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)). For example in your polygon there are 3 points `p1,p2,p3`, we calculate the distance between point `p2` and the line `|p1p3|` , if this distance is less than the given `epsilon` value , `p2` point is removed from polygon. So if you use this function with very small value of `epsilon` (to remove *collinear points*) you can remove all redundant points from all edges your polygon. Try this

```
mpolygon_t out; // to hold new geometry
boost::geometry::simplify(expanded_mpoly,out,0.00001); // very small epsilon value
auto list_coordinates = [](const point_t& pt) {
                            std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
                            std::cout << "vertex(" << get<0>(pt)
                                      << ", " << get<1>(pt) << ")" << std::endl;
                        };
boost::geometry::for_each_point(out, list_coordinates); // print out
```

as output you see

```
vertex(9, 9)
vertex(9, 4)
vertex(4, 4)
vertex(4, 9)
vertex(9, 9)
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! I'm going to wait a little longer before accepting this answer, in case there's an approach that doesn't create the extraneous points.